# How to order color for legend with duplicate values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <-  structure(list(time.course = c("CONTROL", "DAY03", "CONTROL", 
"DAY03", "CONTROL", "DAY03", "CONTROL", "DAY03", "CONTROL", "DAY03", 
"CONTROL", "DAY03", "CONTROL", "DAY03", "CONTROL", "DAY03", "CONTROL", 
"CONTROL", "DAY03", "CONTROL", "DAY03", "CONTROL", "DAY03", "CONTROL", 
"DAY03", "CONTROL", "DAY03", "CONTROL", "DAY03"), percentage = c(0.146567717996289, 
0.272503516174402, 0.0134508348794063, 0.0161744022503516, 0.0166975881261596, 
0.0116033755274262, 0.00602968460111317, 0.00457102672292546, 
0.369202226345083, 0.311884669479606, 0.102504638218924, 0.146272855133615, 
0.0148423005565863, 0.0123066104078762, 0.158163265306122, 0.080168776371308, 
0.000463821892393321, 0.000463821892393321, 0.010196905766526, 
0.0756029684601113, 0.0527426160337553, 0.00974025974025974, 
0.0119549929676512, 0.0482374768089054, 0.0474683544303797, 0.0148423005565863, 
0.00668073136427567, 0.023191094619666, 0.0154711673699015), 
    `UMAP cluster` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
    12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15"), class = "factor"), cell_name = c("Macrophage", 
    "Macrophage", "Enteroendocrine", "Enteroendocrine", "Endothelial", 
    "Endothelial", "Lymphatic", "Lymphatic", "Fibroblast", "Fibroblast", 
    "T cell", "T cell", "Myofibroblast", "Myofibroblast", "Absorptice & secrectory cell", 
    "Absorptice & secrectory cell", "Plasmacytoid DC", "Neutrophil", 
    "Neutrophil", "Plasma cell", "Plasma cell", "Cajal intestinal cell", 
    "Cajal intestinal cell", "Myofibroblast", "Myofibroblast", 
    "Glial cell", "Glial cell", "Germinal center B cell", "Germinal center B cell"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

And with this code:

```
mycolors <- ggsci::pal_simpsons(palette = "springfield")(15)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = time.course, y = percentage, 
                                                    fill = `UMAP cluster`
                                                    # fill = cell_name,
                                                    )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Prop")

p
```

I can make this plot:

[image]

Now what I want to do is to replace the `UMAP Cluster` number with the corresponding
name with this tibble:

```
cluster_no_cell_name_tbl <- tribble(

  ~`UMAP cluster`, ~cell_name,
  1, "Macrophage",
  2, "Enteroendocrine",
  3, "Endothelial",
  4, "Lymphatic", 
  5, "Fibroblast", 
  6, "T cell", 
  7, "Myofibroblast",
  8, "Absorptice & secrectory cell",
  9, "Plasmacytoid DC",
  10, "Neutrophil",
  11, "Plasma cell",
  12, "Cajal intestinal cell",
  13, "Myofibroblast",
  14, "Glial cell",
  15, "Germinal center B cell"
)
```

Note that `myofibroblast` is duplicated, it appears in `UMAP cluster` 7 and 13.

At the end of the day I want the color to be ordered with the following legend name attached:

[image]

How can I do that? I tried to create the factor before plotting but it fails:

```
new_sort_order <- cluster_no_cell_name_tbl %>% pull(cell_name)
dat$`UMAP cluster` <- factor(dat$`UMAP cluster`, levels = new_sort_order)
```

It gives:

```
Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
  factor level [13] is duplicated
```

Comment: Does adding `labels = cluster_no_cell_name_tbl$cell_name` to `scale_fill_manual()` work for you?

Comment: @Z.Lin can you give example. AFAIK `scale_fill_manual()` doesn't allow you to fill the text value.

Comment: `scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors, labels = cluster_no_cell_name_tbl$cell_name)`

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too hard to do using

```
p + theme(legend.text = c("your", "labels", "here"))
```

Comment: @albeti2 That doesn't work. I get `Error in (function (el, elname)  : 
  Element legend.text must be a element_text object`. If you can give working example that would be great.

Comment: Try this: p + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title"))

(or alternatively)

p + scale_fill_discrete(name = "New Legend Title")